# Protractor browser.wait causes angular timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have this code

```
    browser.sleep(5000).then(function() {console.log('rotel:' + browser.rootEl)});
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.rootEl = 'div#overview';
    browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent().then(function() {console.log('Switch default')});
    browser.sleep(500);
    browser.wait(function() { return browser.isElementPresent(by.css('[class="box-header"]'))}, 10000);
    element(by.model("ssn")).sendKeys(pat + "\n").then(function() {console.log('sendkeys')});
    browser.rootEl = 'body';
```

If I remove the line with browser wait the testing continues otherwise i get

> 'Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "root element (body) has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app."'

How can the wait, which don't use any angular things, not work when the "by.model" line does?

Plus I'm almost certain it worked this morning before going out for some errands.

Answer (score 4):

If the page you are testing is angular, then you should set `ignoreSynchronization` to `false` in your code - `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;`.

Also make sure you have `ng-app` attribute on your html body tag without which protractor doesn't recognise if its an angular or non-angular page. If at all your `ng-app` tag is on a descendant element of body tag, then use the property `rootElement` in your conf.js file to indicate protractor to check angular from that tag onwards. Here's how -

```
rootElement: 'body/div', //if ng-app tag is on a div element under body
```

Also the promise that [`isElementPresent()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.isElementPresent) returns is not resolved in your `browser.wait()` function. The `wait()` function always waits for a boolean value to be returned until the timeout value expires and if it doesn't return anything then an error is thrown. Also `isElementPresent()` returns a boolean value based on the element's presence. Here's how to use it -

```
browser.wait(function() { 
    return browser.isElementPresent(by.css('[class="box-header"]')).then(function(present){
        return present;
    });
}, 10000);
```

There's another easy way if you just want to check if the element is present on the DOM by using [`ExpectedConditions`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) object that protractor has. Here are few examples of its usage -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var element = element(by.css('[class="box-header"]'));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 10000); //Checks if element is present and enabled on DOM
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element), 10000); //Checks if element is present on DOM
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element), 10000); //Use it if you want to wait for element to be clickable Checks if element is present and enabled on DOM
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer unfortunately there's no change to the way my test behaves. I still get the timeout for angular.

Comment: @TheBurnMill is your page angular or non-angular? The reason i ask is because you are using `model` locator and you have turned the `ignoreSynchronization` off. Also where is this error occurring exactly - is it on the `wait()` function or `by.model().sendKeys()`? I have updated the answer with an easy way to wait until element's present on the page.

Comment: It is angular however the ng-app isn't on body hence the rootEl lines.

Comment: After trying the "protractor.ExpectedConditions" the result is still the same.

Comment: Ok, then that's the issue. You should have ng-app on the body html tag of your app if its angular as that is the determination factor for protractor to determine if its angular or non-angular web page that you are testing. Updated answer with few comments.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any way to move the ng-app to the body. The error however happens on the wait "line". Because if I remove the wait everything works as long as I keep the sleep part at the top. However I would like to remove the sleep to speed up the test.

Comment: Does setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` help? Also which version of angular are you using? Or you can simply try to wait for angular to settle using `browser.waitForAngular().then(function(){//Your code to work on angular elements});`

Comment: I have tried both true and false. I think the root to al my problems are the surrounding system. The pages that I want to test are embedded in iframes contained within that system. The snippet above is for making this system open my page in the iframe. So perhaps I'll stick to the sleep and accept the wasted time.

Comment: @TheBurnMill i have updated answer with the `rootElement` property that might help you solve your issue. Can you try it? Thanks